# OpenLayers and Vaadin 14

Tags: vaadin, openlayers, vaadin-flow

Does anybody integrated the last OpenLayers and java framework Vaadin 14?
There should use Npm and Webpack and I have tried some approaches described in Vaadin's documentation (https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/web-components/integrating-a-web-component.html). As a result, OpenLayers does not see the target container (according its target property).

I would be appreciated for any advice.

Regards,
Sergey

Comment: please add what you have tried ahd what errors you got so we can improve on it.

Comment: Only empty tag <ol> without Openlayers content, please see the same post on Vaadin forum:https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17987515/integration-opanlayers-6-with-vaadin-14

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer** *:The example below have some problems with controls: they are not rendered correctly. If I will find a solution to this, I will update the answer, but hopefully you could benefit from it already a bit :)*

Update : Problem was partly solved by adding missing styles as described here [Problems using ol3 inside Shadow DOM](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/3264)

1. Create a template where map is defined
2. Run in command line `npm install ol` [NPM openlayers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openlayers)
3. Create a Java counterpart class, which you can use from server-side
4. Add class to a layout

A `openlayers-template.js` file

```js
import {PolymerElement,html} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import {default as TileLayer} from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj.js';

/**
 * `openlayers-template`
 *
 * OpenlayersTemplate element.
 *
 * @customElement
 * @polymer
 */
class OpenlayersTemplate extends PolymerElement {

    static get template() {
        return html`
     //Essential for controls buttons
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v6.1.1/css/ol.css">
            <div>
                <div style="height: 250px;width: 750px;" id="map"></div>
            </div>`;
    }
    ready() {
        super.ready();
        const map = new Map({
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    source: new OSM()
                })
            ],
            view: new View({
                center: fromLonLat([28.9744, 41.0128]),
                zoom: 0
            })
        });
        map.setTarget(this.shadowRoot.getElementById("map"))
    }
    static get is() {
        return 'openlayers-template';
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            // Declare your properties here.
        };
    }
}

customElements.define(OpenlayersTemplate.is, OpenlayersTemplate);
```

And a Java counterpart class:

```java
@Tag("openlayers-template")
@JsModule("./src/openlayers-template.js")
public class OpenlayersTemplate extends PolymerTemplate<OpenlayersTemplate.OpenlayersTemplateModel> {

    /**
     * Creates a new OpenlayersTemplate.
     */
    public OpenlayersTemplate() {
        // You can initialise any data required for the connected UI components here.
        setId("openlayers");
    }

    /**
     * This model binds properties between OpenlayersTemplate and openlayers-template
     */
    public interface OpenlayersTemplateModel extends TemplateModel {
        // Add setters and getters for template properties here.
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: It works, many thanks! Regarding the rendering - we try to fix it and if we'll succeed we post it here

Comment: I found that a `
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v6.1.1/css/ol.css">` should be added--> It looks better after that :)

Comment: Yes, the style applied trough the href, but there is another problem: how to apply (import) the local ol.css (already exists in ./node_modules/ol in project directory). We are new to Polymer, so will be appreciated for the advice)